# Finding a map between two balls for any continously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have some trouble visualizing the following problem:

Function $F(x,t) = \big(x+ty(x),t\big)$ with $y(x)$ a continuously differentiable function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

I need to show that there exist radii $r_1 , r_2 > 0$ with a map between them:
$G: B(0,r_2) \to B(0,r_1)$ such that $(p,q) = F(x,t)$ iff $(x,t) = G(p,q)$, and in the end give an expression for $[\mathrm DG] (p,q)$.

However I cannot visualize how I can create a map between two balls for every continuously differentiable function/how I should visualize and think about this.

**My thought process/progress:**

If $y(x)$ is a monotone increasing function, I do not understand how the second ball that we map onto can be bounded by a specific radius $r_2$. In the images of $F(x,t)$ the $x$-coordinate $\big(x+ty(x)\big)$ keeps increasing so I do not see how such a radius $r_2$ exists. My problem is thus in visualizing the problem wrong in the $\mathbb R^2$ I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the inverse function theorem. The main point is that you can invert a nonlinear function simply by looking at the invertibility of the (linear!) map $DF$. In this case $$DF(x,t)= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
1+ty'(x) & y(x)\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right).
$$
So notice that at $(0,0)=(x,t)$ we have $DF(0,0)$ has determinant 1.

Your intuition in the case that $y$ is monotone that the $x$ coordinate of $f$ increases is not quite correct, it also needs to take into account the variation in the $t$ coordinate for the factor $ty(x)$. This makes it much more difficult to determine, off the formula alone, whether the map in invertible. This is the power of the inverse function theorem; it reduces matters to checking invertibility of a matrix.

Of course, you're right about being a little sketched out by $r_1, r_2$: in general, these are not explicit (other than running through the fixed point argument in the proof of the theorem, but even then it's a generic bound).

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't recognize this theorem but it makes sense now that I look at the theorem statement. So it says that the open sets (these balls) should exist if the determinant is non-zero, which you show at (0,0). Does this immediately prove the existence of these balls? And I understand this part, however how does it now give me DG? The clue of the problem is now clear to me, so thank you already for that :)

Comment: Now it makes total sense, this inverse function - being bijective of course - makes it the map that we are trying to prove exists, since the open sets we now prove exist are open balls (with certain radii) in R^2!

Comment: and DG is just the inverse of proven invertible DF

Comment: You're exactly right! BTW the way I remember the formula for $DG$ is to use the chain rule on the identity $F\circ G= (x, y) $, and solve for $DG$.

Comment: Makes sense because of them being inverses. I can take the Jacobian of both sides and use the chain rule?

Comment: That's correct.